# Display HTML/CSS properly on mobile and desktop

Tags: html, css

Now the code below is displaying perfectly on different mobile platforms and different mobile browsers. For some reason when I load it onto my desktop browser the image overlaps the links.

On mobile the image is perfectly centered above the links and desktop version image is overlapping the links. Any help?

The main issue is the placement of the image.

**CSS:**

```
    html {
  font-size: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn {
  border: 5px solid #2c3e50;
  color: #2c3e50;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'trebuchet ms';
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  }
.btn::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #E26A6A;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 #F1C40F, 
              20px 20px 0 #3498DB;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.25rem;
  top: 0.5rem;
  height: 102%;
  width: 102%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.btn:hover::before {
  box-shadow: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
    .tools
    {
      position:absolute;
      top: 25px;
      left: 0px;
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

**html:**

```
    <body>
    <img src="tools.png" class="tools">
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="btn">< MICROSOFT_LOGGER ></a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="btn">< OFFICE_TOOL_LOGGER ></a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="btn">< WEB_MON_COMPUTER ></a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="btn">< WEB_MON_ANDROID ></a>
</div>
</body>
```

https://codepen.io/brandon-humphrey/pen/wvMGJzN

**Desktop view:** https://ibb.co/6YVZC13


 
**Mobile view:** https://ibb.co/7QFcdn3

Comment: if you want to display "greater than" and "less than" symbols, use `&gt;` and `&lt;` in your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you're using `position: absolute` to position your image. What this does to your element is that it removes it from the normal document flow, and no space is created for it in the page layout anymore.

I recommend you [read more about positioning in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) so that you could figure out what you need and do it!

Small hint: What you might want is using Flexbox mainly to position everything properly, you can have a better result just by setting the `flex-direction` in `body` to `column` (Although I recommend putting your flexbox as styles for divs not the whole body). Also, remove the CSS class you wrote for `tools`, and the height you specified for the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you get the effect you want on mobile is a fluke. The wrapper for buttons is vertically centered, so there's space enough for the image to sit on top and not cover your buttons. Once the vertical space is reduced because the screen is landscape your absolutely positioned image covers the buttons.

If you want the effect to be consistent, I suggest you remove all your styling for the tool class and add `flex-direction:column;` to your body styles. You may still have to fiddle with it for your full effect, but this will get you the basics.